# Spring Cloud Stream + RabbitMQ - Consuming existing messages in queue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have a RabbitMQ message broker running in a server, to which I'm trying to configure a Producer and a Consumer using Spring Cloud Stream. My Producer is creating messages in a queue every second, while my Consumer reads them at the same rate. However, if I stop my Consumer and the Producer keeps pushing messages, when I restart my Consumer again it is unable to retrieve the messages created in that period of time it was down, only picking up the messages produced from the time that it was started. How can I make my Consumer consume existing messages in the queue when it starts?

Here are my Consumer properties:

```
cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: spring-cloud-stream-demo
          consumer:
            auto-bind-dlq: true
            republishToDlq: true
            maxAttempts: 5
```

And my Producer properties:

```
cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: spring-cloud-stream-demo
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `group` to the consumer (input) binding; otherwise it will bind an anonymous, auto-delete, queue to the exchange.

With a `group`, a permanent, durable, queue is bound instead.

Comment: Well... that seemed to do the trick! I came across your suggestion in other threads, but I failed to associate it with my situation. Many thanks, Mr. Russell! Thank you for work in this wonderful tool :-) Best regards!